# Finding the roots of a 3rd order polynomial

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a fucntion of $x^3 -x - r=0$ for $r>0$ and I need to find its roots.

How can I do this ..?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula

Comment: You can check this link https://youtu.be/w6oWUUkOTrI

Answer (score 0):

One solution is given by $$x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 r^2-4}+9
   r}}{\sqrt[3]{2}
   3^{2/3}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt
   {3} \sqrt{27 r^2-4}+9 r}}$$

Answer (score 0):

An odd degree polynomial always has at least one real root, so we can be assured that there exists some $a, b, c$ such that:

\begin{align*}
x^3 - x - r &= (x - a)(x^2 + bx + c) \\
&= x^3 + (b-a)x^2 + (c - ab)x - ac
\end{align*}

Equating coefficients on like powers of $x$ yields:

$b-a = 0, c - ab = -1,\text{ and } ac = r$

Solving this for $a, b,\text{ and } c$ reduces the problem to factoring the quadratic $x^2 + bx + c$ (if possible).